# Retrieve image dimensions from URL

Tags: vb.net, image, url

I'm trying to retrieve image dimensions from an image URL.
How is this possible?
I've done plenty of research and haven't found any code that can achieve this, all of the information gets image dimensions from an image on the local disk which is not what I want.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to download entire file, only first few bytes. If image is `PNG`, width is in 17th, 18th, 19th and 20th byte, and height is in 21st, 22nd, 23rd and 24th byte. If it's `GIF`, width is in 7th and 8th byte, and height is in 9th and 10th byte. It's complicated for `JPG`. Note that byte order in PNG is big-endian(`255` - `000000FF`) and in GIF is little-endian(`255` - `FF00`). Here is code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub GetImageDimensions() Handles Button1.Click
        HTTPWebRequest_GetResponse.Main("http://www.example.com/image.png") 'without slash at end
        Do
            If HTTPWebRequest_GetResponse.done = True Then
                Dim width As Integer = HTTPWebRequest_GetResponse.width
                Dim height As Integer = HTTPWebRequest_GetResponse.height
                Exit Do
            End If
            If HTTPWebRequest_GetResponse.exception Then
                Exit Do 'prevents inifinite loop if exception occured
            End If
        Loop

    End Sub


End Class

Public Class RequestState
    ' This class stores the State of the request. 
    Public requestData As StringBuilder
    Public BufferRead() As Byte
    Public request As HttpWebRequest
    Public response As HttpWebResponse
    Public streamResponse As Stream

    Public Sub New()
        requestData = New StringBuilder("")
        request = Nothing
        streamResponse = Nothing
    End Sub 'New 
End Class 'RequestState


Class HTTPWebRequest_GetResponse

    Private BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 1024
    Public Shared response As String
    Public Shared done As Boolean = False
    Public Shared length As Long = 1
    Public Shared progress As Integer
    Public Shared myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest
    Public Shared myRequestState As New RequestState
    Public Shared status As String
    Private Shared body As Boolean = False
    Public Shared responseStream As Stream
    Private Shared offset As Integer
    Private Shared bytestoread As Integer
    Public Shared width As Integer
    Public Shared height As Integer
    Private Shared imageType As String
    Public Shared exception As Boolean = False

    Shared Sub Main(url As String)
        done = False
        exception = False
        Try
            If url.Substring(url.Length - 4) = ".png" Then
                myRequestState.BufferRead = New Byte(23) {}
                offset = 16
                bytestoread = 24
                imageType = "png"
            ElseIf url.Substring(url.Length - 4) = ".gif" Then
                myRequestState.BufferRead = New Byte(9) {}
                offset = 6
                bytestoread = 10
                imageType = "gif"
            Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("You can only use this with PNG or GIF images.")
            End If


            ' Create a HttpWebrequest object to the desired URL.  
            myHttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)

            ' Create an instance of the RequestState and assign the previous myHttpWebRequest 
            ' object to its request field.   

            myRequestState.request = myHttpWebRequest

            ' Start the asynchronous request. 
            Dim result As IAsyncResult = CType(myHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf RespCallback), myRequestState), IAsyncResult)
        Catch e As WebException
            exception = True
            Debug.WriteLine(ControlChars.Lf + "Main Exception raised!")
            Debug.WriteLine(ControlChars.Lf + "Message: " + e.Message)
            Debug.WriteLine(ControlChars.Lf + "Status: " + e.Status)
        Catch e As Exception
            exception = True
            Debug.WriteLine(ControlChars.Lf + "Main Exception raised!")
            Debug.WriteLine("Source : " + e.Source)
            Debug.WriteLine("Message : " + e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub 'Main

    Private Shared Sub RespCallback(asynchronousResult As IAsyncResult)
        Try
            Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = myRequestState.request
            myRequestState.response = CType(myHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult), HttpWebResponse)

            ' Read the response into a Stream object. 
            Dim responseStream As Stream = myRequestState.response.GetResponseStream()
            myRequestState.streamResponse = responseStream

            ' Begin the Reading of the contents of the HTML page. 

            responseStream.Read(myRequestState.BufferRead, 0, bytestoread)
            If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then
                If imageType = "png" Then
                    height = BitConverter.ToInt32(myRequestState.BufferRead.Skip(offset).Reverse.Take(4).ToArray, 0)
                    width = BitConverter.ToInt32(myRequestState.BufferRead.Skip(offset).Reverse.Skip(4).Take(4).ToArray, 0)
                Else
                    width = BitConverter.ToInt16(myRequestState.BufferRead.Skip(offset).Skip(6).Take(2).ToArray, 0)
                    height = BitConverter.ToInt16(myRequestState.BufferRead.Skip(offset).Skip(8).Take(2).ToArray, 0)
                End If
            Else
                If imageType = "png" Then
                    width = BitConverter.ToInt32(myRequestState.BufferRead.Skip(offset).Skip(16).Take(4).ToArray, 0)
                    height = BitConverter.ToInt32(myRequestState.BufferRead.Skip(offset).Skip(20).Take(4).ToArray, 0)
                Else
                    height = BitConverter.ToInt16(myRequestState.BufferRead.Skip(offset).Reverse.Take(2).ToArray, 0)
                    width = BitConverter.ToInt16(myRequestState.BufferRead.Skip(offset).Reverse.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray, 0)
                End If
            End If
            done = True
            Return
        Catch e As WebException
            exception = True
            Debug.WriteLine(ControlChars.Lf + "RespCallback Exception raised!")
            Debug.WriteLine(ControlChars.Lf + "Message: " + e.Message)
            Debug.WriteLine(ControlChars.Lf + "Status: " + e.Status)
        Catch ex As Exception
            exception = True
            Debug.WriteLine(ControlChars.Lf + "RespCallback Exception raised!")
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub 'RespCallback
End Class
```

Code is large, but I think this is only to download only enough bytes.

Sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gif#Example_GIF_file
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Technical_details
http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.IHDR

Comment: Hey - this is amazing! Seems like exactly what I'm looking for, is it possible you could provide code/examples? If you're willing to, please update your answer, I'm sure it could help others.

Comment: @user3102516 Code added!

Comment: I stand corrected. THANK YOU for this information @srka. I'm aware that just like mp3 files, information is located in certain bytes of the whole thing, but I never knew you could partially just get information from the whole thing. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Thing is...before any information can be retrieved from a certain URL or file or picture from the internet, it has to be downloaded first. It's the reason why Windows has the temp folder. Everything is stored inside the temp folder including the scenario where you're just browsing the internet. So my suggestion would be to do the same thing, download the picture first and save it somewhere and retrieve the information you want, then you can delete the file after if you don't want it anymore.

Comment: The problem is I have to filter through hundreds of images. So it's going to take ages to download like 500 images, then filter through them and eventually after taking 10 minutes to download 500, I might be left with like 20 images. So it's very time consuming.

Comment: I did something like this before. It was an SEO work and if I were to manually search for keywords and pictures and stuff, it would take more than a month to finish. One time I had to work on 23,000 links. So I decided to create a bot program to do the work. It took about 3 hours to finish scanning them all. I don't know if there's a better way to do this but based on countless tutorials I've read through, this is the only way. If anybody has a better idea, I'd appreciate it very much if it was shared so I could learn :)

Comment: And another thing...you can't have your program to scan hundreds of pictures in seconds unless you have a super computer. Afterall, in my case, 3 hours is so much better than 1 month.

Comment: Have you heard about streams before?

Comment: @Neolisk, yes sir, I've heard about streams. I actually made an android app that could stream live videos online. Unfortunately, I never did anything about streaming pictures and stuff using VB.NET. If you have any idea about this, you could share it so we both could learn from you. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, @srka has an idea, so we could both learn from him. :)